# Django __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument using CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to override the `get_form()` method of the `CreateView`.  My web page has two identical forms - one for adding a "registered" team and another for adding an "unregistered" team. If an unregistered team is being added, I want to set the team_name field of the form to "Available".  As you can see in my code below, I tried accomplishing this by overriding the `get_form()` method

```
class TeamCreateView(LeagueContextMixin, CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = TeamForm
    template_name = "leagueapp/editleague.html"
    registered = False # the correct value of registered is passed in urls.py depending on the url that gets hit

    # Overwrite the get_success_url() method
    def get_success_url(self):
        return '/league/editleague/' + self.kwargs.get('league_id')

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form_kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        if not self.registered:
            form_kwargs['team_name'] = "Available"
        return form_class(**form_kwargs)
```

but this gives me the error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'team_name'`.  What am I doing wrong and/or is there a better way to go about this?

Edit:
This is my TeamForm

```
class TeamForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['team_name', 'captain', 'registered', 'team_location', 'phone', 'email', 'team_payment']
        widgets = {
            'team_name':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control input-md'}),
            'captain':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control input-md'}),
            'phone':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control input-md'}),
            'email':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'email'}),
            'team_location':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control input-md'}),
            'team_payment':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'registered':HiddenInput(),
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined an `__init__` method on `TeamForm` that does not allow for the argument `team_name` to be present which is why you get the TypeError when you unpack `form_kwargs` into that `__init__()`. Either update the `__init__` to accept the new kwarg or rewrite the `__init__` to

```
class TeamForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #code
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass values to form initialization like that. It sounds like what you want to do is to provide custom initial data for the team name, so you should be updating the `initial` dict:

```
    if not self.registered:
        form_kwargs.setdefault('initial', {}).update(name="Available")
```

Comment: Sorry I accepted this answer earlier - thought it was what I needed but it appears not.  This raises the error saying that the team_name field is required.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that I could change the `get_form` method like so:

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    if self.registered:
        myform = super().get_form(form_class)
    else:
        myform = TeamForm({'team_name':'Available', 'team_payment':0.00, 'registered':False})
    return myform
```